# Simplify multiple OR statements in a QUERY using IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am trying to query values from a different sheet using a range from the current sheet. Is there a way to simplify the formula and get rid of all the ORs? Like maybe using a FOR loop?

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sample", "Production!A:P"), 
"select Col1, Col6, Col8, Col16 where 
(Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B2&"')  or (Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B3&"')  or
(Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B4&"')  or (Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B5&"')  or 
(Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B6&"')  or (Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B7&"')  or 
(Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B8&"')  or (Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B9&"')  or 
(Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B10&"') or (Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B11&"') or 
(Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B12&"') or (Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B13&"') or 
(Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B14&"') or (Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B15&"') or 
(Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B16&"') or (Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B17&"') or 
(Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B18&"') or (Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B19&"') or 
(Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B20&"') or (Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B21&"') or 
(Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B22&"') or (Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B23&"') or 
(Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B24&"') or (Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B25&"') or 
(Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B26&"') or (Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B27&"') or 
(Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B28&"') or (Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B29&"') or 
(Col8 contains '"&Tracking!B30&"')", 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=FILTER(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("15YS4mri0m23Z5ai0D3xrGoFw0IYpXNrF-vOpaVYZP_I", "Production!A2:P"),
 "select Col1,Col6,Col8,Col16", 0), 
 REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE("15YS4mri0m23Z5ai0D3xrGoFw0IYpXNrF-vOpaVYZP_I", "Production!H2:H"), 
 ".*"&TEXTJOIN(".*|.*", 1, Tracking!B2:B30)&".*"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you but when I use the first example I get the error:

FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 6192. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

And when I use the second example I get error:

No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: This is the book I am querying:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15YS4mri0m23Z5ai0D3xrGoFw0IYpXNrF-vOpaVYZP_I/edit#gid=1431778586

And this is the sheet I am using the query statement on("In" sheet, A1):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lSeI_LxMVhyLQ2M3hLCuXMFA59KnehmdB-KiUn3mISg/edit#gid=393403285

Book2 is querying values from Book1 based on input entered in the Tracking sheet. Thanks.

Comment: @ExissionExission answer updated

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. The code almost works! However it sometimes queries similar items. For instance, I added row 1001 and 1002 to https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15YS4mri0m23Z5ai0D3xrGoFw0IYpXNrF-vOpaVYZP_I/edit#gid=1431778586
When I go to: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lSeI_LxMVhyLQ2M3hLCuXMFA59KnehmdB-KiUn3mISg/edit#gid=393403285 and add 'Black, Leg Leveler' as an item in sheet Tracking, the query formula also queries 'Black, Leg Leveler Socket'. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: well, this kind of expected behavior when dealing with "contains"

Comment: I can see why. Thanks a lot for your time. Even though it is not 100% ideal, it may work for us since the addition at tracking only picks up the specified values.